# How logic.js file work in Hyperledger Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In Hyperledger Composer, is **logic.js** related to **Transaction**?

How to access list from **logic.js**?

Have any good tutorial to understand what can I do in **logic.js** file?

Comment: What do you mean `access list from logic.js`?

Comment: list mean like an array of content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, but doesn't have to have the filename 'logic.js' exclusively. See more here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts
2. You model your Array fields first https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/cto_language.html then code it. Arrays are handled like any javascript array handling. See examples here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/trade-network/lib/logic.js#L45 of results from a query being handled in an array. Also temperatureReadings is an array being handled in the sample networks here https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/v0.16.x/packages/perishable-network/lib/logic.js#L37
3. I would encourage you to try out the tutorials to validate your understanding. https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Though, here is an answer, I'm explaining how `logic.js` related to a `transaction`, so that reader can understand.

Transaction is an asset transfer onto or off the ledger. In `Hyperledger Composer` transaction is defined in model (Contain `.cto` extension) file. In `logic.js`( can be `anything.js`) file contain the `Transaction processor function` to execute the transactions defined in the model file.

Here is sample model file:

```
/**
 * My commodity trading network
 */
namespace org.acme.mynetwork
asset Commodity identified by tradingSymbol {
    o String tradingSymbol
    --> Trader owner
}
participant Trader identified by tradeId {
    o String tradeId
    o String firstName
    o String lastName
}
transaction Trade {
    --> Commodity commodity
    --> Trader newOwner
}
```

In the model file, a `Trade` transaction was defined, specifying a relationship to an asset, and a participant. The `Trade` transaction is intended to simply accept the identifier of the `Commodity` asset which is being traded, and the identifier of the `Trader` participant to set as the new owner.

Here is a logic file which contain JavaScript logic to execute the transactions defined in the model file.

```
/**
 * Track the trade of a commodity from one trader to another
 * @param {org.acme.mynetwork.Trade} trade - the trade to be processed
 * @transaction
 */
async function tradeCommodity(trade) {
    trade.commodity.owner = trade.newOwner;
    let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.acme.mynetwork.Commodity');
    await assetRegistry.update(trade.commodity);
}
```

**Tutorial**

1. [Composer Official Documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html)
2. [IBM Blochain Developer Tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-model-test-your-blockchain-network-with-hyperledger-composer-playground/index.html)

Comment: That's ok, it's from the official tutorial. But I don't understand HOW the function tradeCommodity is connected to the transaction Trade. There is no match between the name of the function, and the name of the transaction, or the name of the file... I can't believe that the only connection between the transaction and the function is the comment * @param {org.acme.mynetwork.Trade} trade